# git-how to maintain multiple repositories inside one repository

Tags: git, github

Probably this can be solved using [submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules), but I don't know how in this case.

I am thinking of this hierarchy:

```
web-app-repo/
   .git
   README.md
   fontend-repo/
      .git
      README.md
   backend-repo/
      .git
      README.md
```

The web-app-repo is a remote one. The other two repos are local ones.
If possible, how can I do this?

I need to be able to make updates on my machine and push commits to their respective remote repos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the way to go is using submodules, but you should publish the submodules if you want to include them in a published project.

When you have some submodule in a project what you have is simple a "pointer" to the commit that identifies your submodule status.

If you make changes in some of your submodules and you commit those changes to your project this pointer will be updated to track the new status of your submodule.

When you or some of your team do a "submodule update" git simply loads your submodule in the status of that commit.
If the submodule is not published the users of your project will not be able to update the submodules in that commit and git will give you an error.

If you don't want the code of your submodules to be public probably you need to convert your submodules in packages.

Comment: Ok. So, If I understood what you said, in this case frontend-repo should be added as a submodule of web-app-repo and should have its own remote repo. And the same thing for backend-repo. So if I am pushing a commit to one the submodules I am basically pushing it the respective remote repo of the submodule.

Comment: Yes, thats it. What I do is first create a copy of fontend-repo and create remote project of it. Then include it as a submodule of "main" project. Then if you want you could remove the stand-alone copy as you will never use it. The nice thing is that if you use that library in a separate project you could have different versions in each project and update the other projects to the "last version" of your library when you need it....

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense! What do you mean by stand-alone copy?

Comment: Sorry, I mean for example a copy of "backend-repo" not included as a submodule in any project. You only need it to create the repository but it will always we included in some other project....

Comment: But if I want to update the submodule, I need the respective remote repo to be there. Why would I want to delete the remote, if the submodule is pointing to it?

Comment: No, of course you should mantain the remote. What you can remove is the the local copy used to create it. The remote should be not in your machine, but in some git server as github, bitbucket, or something similar to allow the other users to use it.

Comment: Oh ok I got it, this makes sense, the local copy is expendable in this case. Thank you so much for your help I really appreciate it!